# Match and set child's ID based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a primary incremental **ID** column and have to find and set all its childs (in **ParentID** column) based on values from two other columns (*Condition1* and *Condition2*)
Started ParentID always has Condition2 = 1 (and the same value in Condition1 column)

**Initial table**

```
+---------------------------------------------
|  ID |  ParentID  | Condition1 | Condition2 |
+---------------------------------------------
|  1  |       null |      1000  |          1 |
|  2  |       null |      1000  |       null |
|  3  |       null |      1000  |       null |
|  4  |       null |      2000  |          1 |
|  5  |       null |      2000  |       null |
|  6  |       null |      2000  |       null |
|  7  |       null |      3000  |          1 |
|  8  |       null |      3000  |       null | 
|  9  |       null |      3000  |       null |
+---------------------------------------------
```

**Desired Output**

```
+---------------------------------------------
|  ID |  ParentID  | Condition1 | Condition2 |
+---------------------------------------------
|  1  |          1 |      1000  |          1 |
|  2  |          1 |      1000  |       null |
|  3  |          1 |      1000  |       null |
|  4  |          4 |      2000  |          1 |
|  5  |          4 |      2000  |       null |
|  6  |          4 |      2000  |       null |
|  7  |          7 |      3000  |          1 |
|  8  |          7 |      3000  |       null | 
|  9  |          7 |      3000  |       null |
+---------------------------------------------
```

Current code returns only one row for each new ID

```
update u 
set u.ParentID = u.ID
from [db].[dbo].[tbl] u
  inner join [db].[dbo].[tbl]  on 
        u.Condition2 = 1 and u.Condition1 = u.Condition1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one intuitive way of doing this is

```
UPDATE [db].[dbo].[tbl] u
SET u.ParentID = (SELECT id FROM [db].[dbo].[tbl] u2 WHERE u2.condition1 = u.condition1 and u2.condition2 = 1)
```

I don't mean that this is better than what you're trying to do, just that I think it's very intuitive and easy to understand if you're having issues.

I think the solution you are looking for is:

```
update u 
set u.ParentID = u2.ID
from [db].[dbo].[tbl] u
  inner join [db].[dbo].[tbl] u2  on 
        u2.Condition2 = 1 and u.Condition1 = u2.Condition1
```

The important differences here are that I have given the both tables in the join-to-self a name (u and u2). You don't want to set `u.ParentID = u.ID` (as in your question), you want to set `u.ParentID = u2.ID` (note the 2). Similarly, you don't want to join the tables on `u.condition1 = u.condition1` (since that is always true in this example) or `u.condition2 = 1` (since you're applying that condition to the table you're updating, not the table you joined). Even though it is a join-to-self, you need to be clear about which table you are referencing. `u` in your query refers to the table being updated, but not the table on the right-side of the join.

Comment: Nice and simple trick! Have to think over all its graceful depth later... While its work and that's fine. I thought more in the direction of CTE recursions, but slightly messed up when applying to my case